# How to prove that $x\mapsto x^{\frac35}$ is continuous

Tags: calculus, continuity

Trying to teach myself calc and I know what continuity is but how exactly do we write a formal proof proving that a function is continuous.

Say the function $f(x) = x^{\frac35}$. How would I write the step-by-step proof of why it is continuous?

Comment: It depends how much you already know.E.g. if $f(x)$ is continuous then $f(x)^n$ is continuous for positive integer $n$ and $f(x)^{1/m}$ is continuous for ODD positive integer $m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $x^{\frac35}=e^{\frac35\log x}$. Since $\log$ is defined as $$\log x = \int_1^x \frac1t \ \mathsf dt$$ for $x>0$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $\log$ is continuous. Moreover, $e^x = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$. Since $$g_n(x) := \left(1+\frac xn\right)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk \left(\frac xn\right)^k $$ is a polynomial, $g_n$ is continuous. As $$g_n'(x) = \left(1+\frac xn\right)^{n-1} + \frac1n\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n = \left(1 +\frac xn \right)^{n-1}\left(1+\frac1n\right) $$
and $g_n'(x)=0$ implies $x=-n$. Since $g_n'\geqslant 0$ on $[0,\infty)$, and $[0,\infty)$ is a connected set which is not bounded above, it follows that any extreme value must be obtained at $x=0$. Hence
$$\sup_{x\in[0,\infty)}|g_n(x) - e^x| = |g_n(0) - e^0| =0. $$
Therefore $g_n$ converges uniformly to $\exp$, from which we conclude that $\exp$ is continuous. Now, $f(x) = g(h(x))$ where $g(x) = e^x$ and $h(x)=\frac35\log x$. The composition of continuous functions is continuous, so $f$ is indeed continuous.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you can reprove this : " It depends how much you already know.E.g. if f(x)
f
x
 is continuous then f(x)n
f
x
n
 is continuous for positive integer n
n
 and f(x)1/m
f
x
1
m
 is continuous for ODD positive integer m
m
. "

if not, continuity means from left or from right of the point, the limit of f in this point is the value of f in this point.
You should use the normal definition of continuity and limits, and try to prove it (i.e. found for a epsilon which etha (x-a) will be egual or less, will make (f(x)-f(a)) egual or less than epsilon.

It sounds like it will be easier to proove first for any continuous function at the power n, and then for any continus function at the power 1/m . good luck